# Mysql less than or equal + not equal 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Mysql code

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE (bandwidth<='$calc_total_bandwidth' AND username!='$usern') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

bandwidth<='$calc_total_bandwidth' = less than or equal

but i'm stuck on how I also can make it so it's "not equal 0"?

Comment: No, not working with SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE (bandwidth<='$calc_total_bandwidth' AND != 0 AND username!='$usern') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: You need a condition... I only posted pseudo code. You'd need to reference a column, something like `AND bandwidth != 0`

Comment: `WHERE bandwidth <= '$calc_total_bandwidth' AND bandwidth != 0`...

Comment: Or `WHERE bandwidth BETWEEN 1 AND $calc_total_bandwidth`

Answer (score 0):

Just `AND` a `!=0` in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT * FROM `members`
WHERE `bandwidth` != 0
AND `bandwidth` <= '$calc_total_bandwidth' 
AND `username` != '$usern'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```